Bi-Directional Viewpager For Both Vertical and Horizontal Scrolling
I am building an app where users can scroll both horizontally and vertically. Imagine a grid box which every square can be wandered by scrolling horizontally and vertically. So far, I have managed changing fragment pages horizontally and vertically but vertical page transformation does not work. I don't seem to handle touch events accordingly. What's the issue?
public class BiDirectionalViewPager extends ViewPager {

private float lastX = 0;
private float lastY = 0;

public BiDirectionalViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public BiDirectionalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float deltaX = Math.abs(x - lastX);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(y - lastY);

            if (deltaY > deltaX) { // Vertical scroll
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(canScrollVertically((int) (lastY - y)));
            } else { // Horizontal scroll
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(canScrollHorizontally((int) (lastX - x)));
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
    }

    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Remove the call to onTouchEvent(event) from here
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically(int direction) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void setPageTransformer(boolean reverseDrawingOrder, PageTransformer transformer) {
    super.setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer(transformer));
}

private static class VerticalPageTransformer implements PageTransformer {
    private final PageTransformer mPageTransformer;

    VerticalPageTransformer(PageTransformer pageTransformer) {
        mPageTransformer = pageTransformer;
    }

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        view.setTranslationX(-position * view.getWidth());
        view.setTranslationY(position * view.getHeight());
        if (mPageTransformer != null) {
            mPageTransformer.transformPage(view, position);
        }
    }
}

}
